# canWrite() not returning value as expected

Tags: java, file-permissions

I am trying to create a file in a specific directory and before that checking directory has write access and if yes,creating a file.Though canWrite() returning true but it is giving PermissionException while creating.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String downloadPath="\\\\pc.liferay.com\\lfs\\zone\\asia\\banglore";
        StringBuilder fileName=new StringBuilder();
        fileName.append(downloadPath);      
        fileName.append(File.separator);
        fileName.append("liferay-");
        fileName.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date()));
        fileName.append(".csv");
        //new File(fileName.toString());
         try {
              File destLocation = new File(downloadPath.toString());
              System.out.println("Abstract path: "+destLocation);            
              System.out.println("Write access? "+destLocation.canWrite());           
                if(destLocation.canWrite()) {
                  File destFile = new File(fileName.toString());
                  System.out.println("File path:"+destFile.getPath()); 
                  if (destFile.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("File created: " + destFile.getPath());
                  } else {
                    System.out.println("File already exists.");
                  }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

Output:

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at com.local.file.downloader.PermissionExcpetionTH.main(PermissionExcpetionTH.java:29)
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a Java bug / feature.  If you search the [Java Bugs database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/), there are a number of bug reports concerning the inconsistent behavior of `canWrite()` and `canRead()` on Windows systems.

The basic problem is that when Microsoft added support for NTFS file systems to the Win32 library, they neglected to "teach" the access check calls to understand NTFS ACLS.  Instead, the old calls still report read/write-ability based solely on the MSDOS permissions.  New API methods were added to handle NTFS file system access check, but application code (in this case the JVM) needs to be changed to use them.

Judging from the Java bug reports, the reaction of the Sun Java team when they discovered that this misfeature had broken Java on WindowsNT was to (rightly) say "this is a Windows bug".  But Microsoft did not fix it.  And it was soon too late for the Sun engineers to apply the workaround to the Java native implementation.  The end result is that `File.canRead()` and `File.canWrite()` can give incorrect results on Windows in some circumstances.

The related Java bugs have been marked as WontFix.

---

So what is the solution?

One solution is to use `Files.isReadable()` and `Files.isWritable()` instead.  My understanding is that one of the (many) things that they fixed in `Files` was the anomalous behavior of the `File.canRead()` and `File.canWrite()` methods.

However, my recommendation is to not bother to test whether files exist, are readable or are writable.  Just attempt to do the file operation and deal with the exceptions.  This has the following advantages:

- It avoids having to deal with inconsistencies in access control.  (For example, there are inconsistencies in Linux when you are using SE-Linux.  File access can be blocked by SE-Linux despite being allowed by allowed by file permission bits and ACLs.)
- It avoids race conditions where something else (another thread, or another program) changes file system permissions at the wrong time.

It is also advisable to switch to using the newer `java.nio.*.*` APIs rather than the old `File` class.  The newer APIs give better diagnostics.

Answer (score -1):

```
 * @param      file   the system-dependent filename.
 * @exception  SecurityException  if the calling thread does not
 *             have permission to access the specified file.
 * @exception  NullPointerException if the file argument is null.
 * @see        #checkPermission(java.security.Permission) checkPermission
 */
 public void checkWrite(String file) {
     checkPermission(new FilePermission(file,
         SecurityConstants.FILE_WRITE_ACTION));
 }
```

So you do not have permission to write into file. You can change this permission in 2 ways.

1. By using command prompt(Windows) or Terminal(Linux or Mac)
2. You can use easily file.setWriteable(true)

   *If `true`, sets the access permission to allow write operations; if `false` to disallow write operations.

Moreover, If you do not want to change access rights and If you do not want to write into this path in case of no permission. You can catch the error and You can create a new file as you wish. The next code piece can help you a bit If you choose this way.

```
    try {
        boolean canWrite = destLocation.canWrite();
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        //Do what you need here.
    }
```